# Xdebug with PHP 5.2 on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: php, drupal, 64-bit, xdebug, php-5.2

I would like to install Xdebug (http://xdebug.org/) on my 64 bit Windows 7 machine to debug Drupal code running on PHP 5.2. The Xdebug download page does not provide a download for a 64 bit version compatible with PHP 5.2.

Many Drupal modules are not compatible with PHP 5.3, so it is not an option to switch to a later version of PHP.

What options exist for installing Xdebug in this environment? Is there another source for compiled versions or is there a work-around?

Comment: May be using virtual machines (like Sun VirtualBox) will better solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `php-5.2.5-x64-2007-11-12.zip` from http://www.fusionxlan.com/PHPx64.php. In the `ext\` folder there is a `php_xdebug.dll` which should work on your Windows x64 machine. Add the reference to it in your php.ini like normal and it should work.

Comment: Looks interesting. Have you used this yourself?

Comment: yeah, it's the only x64 binary with the `apache2handler` sapi. but now i use my own version for PHP 5.3: http://tommymontgomery.com/php64

Comment: Any chance that someone might have a copy of the php_xdebug.dll from fusionxlan?  The site is down and this would be very helpful for me.  I have to run PHP 5.2 and all of the 64 bit xdebug dlls require 5.3

Comment: @Jonathan Day - you might try contacting Derick Rethans (the author of xdebug) directly and requesting it; in my experience he's been pretty accommodating for that kind of stuff.